# Elastic search minimize the boost factor as time pass

Tags: elasticsearch

I have elastic search document that looks like this:

```
...
{
    title : "post 1",
    total_likes : 100,
    total_comments : 129,
    updated_at : "2020-10-19"
},
...
```

And i use a query that boost the likes and comments with respect to the post creation date
so it look like this:

```
total_likes^6,
total_comments^4,
updated_at
```

now the issue with this approach, that if some post had a huge number of likes it will stuck on top of the results forever no matter when it is created.

How i can minimize the boost as the time pass, for example a very fresh post will have the full boost factor (6,4) however, a post that has been created 1 year ago will have the factors (2,1) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think what you are look for is the `function score` in coordination with the `decay factor` [[doc]](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-decay)

Or if your logic is more complex, you could write it in `painless` in the `function field value factor` [[doc]](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-field-value-factor)